# Why PyTorch MultiheadAttention is considered as activation function?

Tags: neural-networks, attention

When I scroll all activation functions available on PyTorch package ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#non-linear-activations-weighted-sum-nonlinearity)), I found that `nn.MultiheadAttention` is described there. Can you please explain why it's considered activation function? Maybe I understand something wrong, but Multihead Attention have it's own learnable weights, so it seems to be more suitable for `Layers`, and not activation functions. Can you please explain me what I'm getting wrong.

Thank you!